# Validation while defining a join

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

I'm trying to define a validation, to include only users that meet specific criteria - mainly, to take into account users whose metadata (that is stored in another table) has field `supplier_id` with specific value. As such, I've done this in `UpdateXRequest` class:

```
public function rules()
{
     $journey = $this->route()->parameter('journey');

     return ['driver_id' => [
          Rule::exists('users', 'id')
               ->where(function($query) use ($journey){
                     $query->join('users_meta', 'users.id', '=', 'users_meta.user_id')
                         ->where('users_meta.key', 'supplier_id')
                         ->where('users_meta.value', $journey->supplier_id);
               })
          ]
     ];
}
```

However, I'm getting `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'users_meta.key' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from users where id = x and (users_meta.key = supplier_id and users_meta.value = y))` error.

How can I accomplish this?

---

I'm looking for answers that use the **default** Laravel logic, rather than writing my own validator

---

Per request, here're the schema queries:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `role_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users_meta` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'null',
  `key` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `value` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE `users`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `users_email_unique` (`email`);

ALTER TABLE `users`
  MODIFY `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

ALTER TABLE `users_meta`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `users_meta_user_id_index` (`user_id`),
  ADD KEY `users_meta_key_index` (`key`);

ALTER TABLE `users_meta`
  MODIFY `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `email`, `password`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, `role_id`) VALUES (6898, 'a@b.com', '', '2017-08-09 12:15:05', '2017-08-09 13:19:56', 4);

INSERT INTO `users_meta` (`id`, `user_id`, `type`, `key`, `value`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES (18, 6898, 'string', 'supplier_id', '6897', '2017-08-09 12:15:05', '2017-08-09 12:15:05');
```

---

The query existed in OP, but per request added SQL query that is produced taken from the query log:

```
select count(*) as aggregate from `users` where `id` = 7011 and (`users_meta`.`key` = supplier_id and `users_meta`.`value` = 6897)
```

---

Thinking more about it, it all makes perfect sense why it's not working - the internal `join` doesn't have any conditions on it (it's still weird that it doesn't appear in query log - maybe it's an optimisation done by Laravel to not unnecessarily join tables for `where` as opposed to `select`). Internal `where`s at this moment are run on `users`, and not on the table from the `join` - and per https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#joins (Advanced Join Clauses), they need to be inside `join` for it to work (per @DarkMukke's answer)

Comment: Shouldn't your `drivers` table join the `users` table too before you use `users.id` in your join for the `users_meta`?

Comment: @ChinLeung - sorry, that was a typo; revisited the code today and it should have been `users` there

Comment: Can you show us the structure of both tables please? :)

Comment: @ChinLeung added

Comment: i think you got the where and join the wrong way around

Comment: @DarkMukke which where? :D Can you please show how you think it should be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a 100% sure, but logically it sounds like the where conditions on your join should be in a Closure

```
public function rules()
{
    $journey = $this->route()->parameter('journey');

    return ['driver_id' => [
        Rule::exists('users', 'id')
            ->where(function($query) use ($journey){
                $query->join('users_meta', function ($join) use ($journey) {
                    $join->on('users.id', '=', 'users_meta.user_id')
                        ->where('users_meta.key', 'supplier_id')
                        ->where('users_meta.value', $journey->supplier_id);
                });
            })
        ]
    ];
}
```

<strike>And even then, you might not need the first closure, eg</strike> 
I was wrong, the where relates to the condition of the Rule, not the where condition of a query builder.

EDIT : I've not tried this code, but from my experience, and some double checking in the docs, this should be correct.

Additionally, since the conditions are all on the join, you could make it faster by joining less data, by adding conditions instead

```
public function rules()
{
    $journey = $this->route()->parameter('journey');

    return [
        'driver_id' => [
            Rule::exists('users', 'id')
                ->where(function ($query) use ($journey) {
                    $query->join('users_meta', function ($join) use ($journey) {
                        $join->on('users.id', '=', 'users_meta.user_id')
                            ->on('users_meta.key', '=', 'supplier_id')
                            ->on('users_meta.value', '=', $journey->supplier_id);
                    });
                })
        ]
    ];
}
```

Comment: The first works, though following the Builder queries (which `$query` is instance of), it shouldn't make a difference, as `join` should be chained (instead being passed as a closure). The second one I've tried before, and it gives a  `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Validation\Rules\Exists::join()`

Comment: check my edit, because you can have multiple join conditions, which strips out the need for a where in the first place. can you show us the SQL it generates, because the join is not there at all in your question

Comment: Um.. `join` is there in my question - `$query->join('users_meta', 'users.id', '=', 'users_meta.user_id')`. The third one is variation of the first, and it will work as well afaik (and indeed it will be faster as it's join on specific data, rather than restricting joined rows to specific set)

Comment: added; the join is not in the query, but it is in the method calls (but we already knew that based on the errors ;))

Comment: i deleted the second one, as per my edit ;) and i was wondering what my code gives you as a query ? eg the because the join is in a closure, when the join doesn't happen, it shouldn't error on the where (or additional join  conditions) as it is contained

Comment: I've edited the OP to include my thoughts on that matter - you're correct that I used `join` incorrectly - I've got confused by `join` on `select` where you just chain the methods, and, apparently if you want to do `where` (or any other operation for that matter) on joined table, you have to use a closure, otherwise the joined table will not be in the final query. I'm completely satisfied :)